# Explanation of Replacing Summation and Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

Please explain the below line in detail -

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}-  \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^s}dx= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right) dx$$

How the summation and integration came in-front of the both expression and why the integration has different limit value?

The source of the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186821/detailed-proof-of-zetas-1-s-1-extends-holomorphically-to-res0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is any integrable function over $[1,+\infty)$ (in your case $f(x)=1/x^s$ with $s>1$), then
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\int_{1}^{N}f(x)dx= \lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)dx$$
and 
$$f(n)= f(n)(n+1-n)=f(n)\int_{n}^{n+1} dx=\int_{n}^{n+1}f(n) dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1 , I think I can , seems reasonable, but if it is okay, can you tell me where I can find a rigorous proof of the first part, just tell me name of any book or pdf file I will find myself.

Comment: @Andrew I added a few details for the first part. If a function is integrable over $[1,+\infty)$ then the first equality holds by definition, the second equality is a standard property of integration, and the last one follows from the definition of series.