# Application of Mean Value Theorem in Proving Convergence (PNT)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

In the proof of PNT by Don Zagier, he wrote below lines-

> The series on the right (which is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1}
>  \left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right) dx$) converges absolutely for
>   $R(s)>0$  because-
>
> $$ \left |\int_{n}^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right) dx\right|=
>  \left |s\int_{n}^{n+1}  \int_{n}^{x} \frac{du}{u^{s+1}} dx\right| \le
>  \frac{|s|}{n^{R(s)+1}}$$ by the mean value theorem.

I don't understand how the  mean value theorem implies the convergence, can anyone please explain? I am new to the topic. Thanks!

The source of the question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186821/detailed-proof-of-zetas-1-s-1-extends-holomorphically-to-res0).

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-p}$ converges when $p >1$, and so one can apply the comparison test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left |\int_{n}^{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right) dx\right|=
 \left |s\int_{n}^{n+1}  \int_{n}^{x} \frac{du}{u^{s+1}} dx\right| \le
 \frac{|s|}{n^{R(s)+1}}
$

Since
$u^{s+1} \ge n^{s+1}
$
for $u \ge n$,

$\begin{array}\\
 \int_{n}^{x} \frac{du}{u^{s+1}} 
&\le  \int_{n}^{x} \frac{du}{n^{s+1}} \\
&=  \frac{x-n}{n^{s+1}} \\
\text{so}\\
\int_{n}^{n+1}  \int_{n}^{x} \frac{du}{u^{s+1}} dx
&\le \int_{n}^{n+1}  \frac{x-n}{n^{s+1}}  dx\\
&=\dfrac1{n^{s+1}} \int_{0}^{1}  x dx\\
&=\dfrac1{2n^{s+1}} \\
\end{array}
$

You can put in absolute value signs
for complex $s$.

Comment: this might be a silly question but where does the mean value theorem comes?

Comment: Actually, that's a good question. You could use it by choosing a value in the range $[n, x]$ and then noting that $1/u^{s+1}$ is decreasing so it is at most the value at the stat of the range. I just skipped a step.

Comment: If possible please add the explanation elaborately to your answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404350/inequalityprime-between-pix-and-pix1-epsilon-when-epsilon0