# Inequality:Prime between $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(x^{1-\epsilon})$ when $\epsilon>0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

$\theta(x) :=\sum_{p\leq x}\log{p}$, if $\epsilon>0$, then  how it is possible to write that-
$$\sum_{x^{1-\epsilon}< p\leq x}\log{p} \geq (1-\epsilon) (\log{x}) (\pi(x)-\pi(x^{1-\epsilon}))?$$

Because, There is no prime between $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(x^{1-\epsilon})$, so, $(\pi(x)-\pi(x^{1-\epsilon}))=0$ when $\epsilon \leq 1$, so definitely I am missing something, can any one explain how can we get above inequality ?

The source of the question is below theorem-

[image]

Comment: It is trivial that $\theta(x)-\theta(x^r) \ge r \log x (\pi(x)-\pi(x^r))$.

Comment: @reuns it would be kind of you if you elaborately present an answer, I am not a student of math

Comment: $\theta(b)-\theta(a)=\sum_{p\in (a,b]} \log p \ge \sum_{p \in (a,b]} \log a=(\pi(b)-\pi(a))\log a$